# Find elements are hidden but display is block before print

Tags: html, css, asp.net, google-chrome, firefox

How to know exactly which elements are hidden but display is block before print?

With Chrome, I'm using **Emulate CSS Media**. But It doesn't show which elements are hidden and display is block. So there are many blank pages in print.

Does anyone know a tip/trick to resolve this problem?

Thanks